# Random fields in physics - how do they work?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, randomness

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of what random fields are. Wikipedia's article gives a formal definition (which is in very mathematical language), but also says various much more intuitive ways to picture the random field, such as:

> [A random field] is a function ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ that takes on a random value at each point ${\displaystyle x\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$ (or some other domain).

However, if each point indeed takes on a random value, then there's no guarantee the random field is continuous. If $f(x) = k$ where $x$ is a position vector, there's no guarantee that $f(x+\epsilon) \neq \exp(k^3)+100000-\mathrm{Sin}(3\pi)$. But if $f(x)$ can fluctuate so wildly with position, then it surely 
wouldn't relate to the universe at all - physical quantities don't vary by much over very small displacements.

Wikipedia touches on this:

> When used in the natural sciences, values in a random field are often spatially correlated. For example, adjacent values (i.e. values with adjacent indices) do not differ as much as values that are further apart. This is an example of a covariance structure, many different types of which may be modeled in a random field.

However I do not understand this: if there is some kind of structure in the field, then it is (by definition) not random.

It seems to me there must be more to a random field than just random numbers at every point, in particular some guarantee that the field is at least continuous, even if it's not differentiable (although that seems like a reasonable assumption to make for physical fields too). Am I understanding this right? If so, where is the continuity condition imposed in the definition? If not, why do we not need continuity?

Comment: "However I do not understand this: if there is some kind of structure in the field, then it is (by definition) not random." That's the key issue. That is far too restrictive a definition of randomness. All that "random" means is that there's some component that isn't deterministic. The game of poker has structure too -- would you call it nonrandom?

Comment: One example of a way to construct a random field is to choose independent random values for its Fourier components, but have the distribution get more sharply peaked about zero the larger the Fourier wavenumber is. If you apply this properly, you can almost always get a continuous function. (This is a simple description of how a field in thermal equilibrium would behave.)